# R - conditionally creating multiple variables (factor percentages)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe, dplyr

R version 3.4.2

I am trying to create 3 new variables according to conditions based on other variables of the same dataframe. I managed to achieve what I intended, but it requires several lines of code to produce an output that I think other methods (possibly using dplyr) might deliver much effortlessly.

Here is a reproductible example:

```
city <- c("London", "London", "Leeds","Leeds", "Leeds", "Nottingham", "Glasgow", "Belfast", "Belfast", "Oxford", "Oxford", "Southampton", "Aberdeen", "Bath", "Bath", "Bath", "Preston", "Preston", "Liverpool", "Derby","Hereford")

transport <- c("cars", "scooters", "cars", "scooters", "bikes", "cars", "scooters", "cars", "bikes", "scooters", "bikes", "bikes", "scooters", "cars", "scooters", "bikes", "scooters", "bikes", "bikes", "cars", "bikes")

number <- c("153", "21", "267", "87", "13", "95", "17", "199", "8", "34", "5", "23", "40", "142", "79", "28", "37", "22", "19", "83", "23")

df <- data.frame(city, transport, number)
```

What I want is to know the **percentage of each type of transportation in each city**, like so:

```
> df
          city transport number pct.cars pct.scooters pct.bikes
1       London      cars    153    87.93        12.07      0.00
2       London  scooters     21    87.93        12.07      0.00
3        Leeds      cars    267    72.75        23.71      3.54
4        Leeds  scooters     87    72.75        23.71      3.54
5        Leeds     bikes     13    72.75        23.71      3.54
6   Nottingham      cars     95   100.00         0.00      0.00
7      Glasgow  scooters     17     0.00       100.00      0.00
8      Belfast      cars    199    96.14         0.00      3.86
9      Belfast     bikes      8    96.14         0.00      3.86
10      Oxford  scooters     34     0.00        87.18     12.82
11      Oxford     bikes      5     0.00        87.18     12.82
12 Southampton     bikes     23     0.00         0.00    100.00
13    Aberdeen  scooters     40     0.00       100.00      0.00
14        Bath      cars    142    57.03        31.73     11.24
15        Bath  scooters     79    57.03        31.73     11.24
16        Bath     bikes     28    57.03        31.73     11.24
17     Preston  scooters     37     0.00        62.71     37.29
18     Preston     bikes     22     0.00        62.71     37.29
19   Liverpool     bikes     19     0.00         0.00    100.00
20       Derby      cars     83   100.00         0.00      0.00
21    Hereford     bikes     23     0.00         0.00    100.00
```

The code that produces the data frame above is the following:

```
df <- tbl_df(df) %>%
  mutate(., pct.cars = rep(as.numeric(0), length.out = length(df$city)),
            pct.scooters = rep(as.numeric(0), length.out = length(df$city)),
            pct.bikes = rep(as.numeric(0), length.out = length(df$city)))


for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

  cur_city <- df$city[i]
  n_cars <- df$number[df$city == cur_city & df$transport == "cars"]
  n_scooters <- df$number[df$city == cur_city & df$transport == "scooters"]
  n_bikes <- df$number[df$city == cur_city & df$transport == "bikes"]

  if (length(n_cars) == 1 & length(n_scooters) < 1 & length(n_bikes) < 1) {
    # case: there are no scooters nor bikes

    df$pct.cars[i] <- 100
    df$pct.scooters[i] <- 0
    df$pct.bikes[i] <- 0

  } else if (length(n_cars) < 1 & length(n_scooters) == 1 & length(n_bikes) == 1) {
    # case: there are no cars

    df$pct.cars[i] <- 0
    df$pct.scooters[i] <- (n_scooters/(n_scooters + n_bikes))*100
    df$pct.bikes[i] <- (n_bikes/(n_scooters + n_bikes))*100

  } else if (length(n_cars) == 1 & length(n_scooters) == 1 & length(n_bikes) < 1) {
    # case: there are no bikes

    df$pct.cars[i] <- (n_cars/(n_cars + n_scooters))*100
    df$pct.scooters[i] <- (n_scooters/(n_cars + n_scooters))*100
    df$pct.bikes[i] <- 0

  } else if (length(n_cars) == 1 & length(n_scooters) < 1 & length(n_bikes) == 1) {
    # case: there are no scooters

    df$pct.cars[i] <- (n_cars/(n_cars + n_bikes))*100
    df$pct.scooters[i] <- 0
    df$pct.bikes[i] <- (n_bikes/(n_cars + n_bikes))*100

  } else if (length(n_cars) < 1 & length(n_scooters) == 1 & length(n_bikes) < 1) {
    # case: there are no cars nor bikes

    df$pct.cars[i] <- 0
    df$pct.scooters[i] <- 100
    df$pct.bikes[i] <- 0

  } else if (length(n_cars) < 1 & length(n_scooters) < 1 & length(n_bikes) == 1) {
    # case: there are no cars nor scooters

    df$pct.cars[i] <- 0
    df$pct.scooters[i] <- 0
    df$pct.bikes[i] <- 100

  } else if (length(n_cars) == 1 & length(n_scooters) == 1 & length(n_bikes) == 1 ) {
    # case: there are cars, scooters & bikes

    df$pct.cars[i] <- (n_cars/(n_cars + n_scooters + n_bikes))*100
    df$pct.scooters[i] <- (n_scooters/(n_cars + n_scooters + n_bikes))*100
    df$pct.bikes[i] <- (n_bikes/(n_cars + n_scooters + n_bikes))*100

  }
}
```

If somebody has got an **easier solution or suggestion (possibly using dplyr)**, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: One liner in base R: `prop.table(xtabs(as.numeric(as.character(number)) ~ city + transport, data=df), 1)`

Comment: ...or just `prop.table(xtabs(number ~ city + transport, data=df), 1)` if you start with a numeric variable for `number` instead of a factor.

Comment: Awesome - it's so simple! Thank you very much, @thelatemail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
df %>%
    group_by(city) %>%
    mutate(
        number = as.numeric(as.character(number)),
        ntot = sum(number),
        percentage = number / ntot * 100,
        id = paste0("perc.", transport)) %>%
    spread(id, percentage) %>%
    replace(., is.na(.), 0) %>%
    select(-ntot) %>%
    ungroup()
#   city     transport number perc.bikes perc.cars perc.scooters
#   <fct>    <fct>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 Aberdeen scooters   40.0        0          0           100
# 2 Bath     bikes      28.0       11.2        0             0
# 3 Bath     cars      142          0         57.0           0
# 4 Bath     scooters   79.0        0          0            31.7
# 5 Belfast  bikes       8.00       3.86       0             0
# 6 Belfast  cars      199          0         96.1           0
# 7 Derby    cars       83.0        0        100             0
# 8 Glasgow  scooters   17.0        0          0           100
# 9 Hereford bikes      23.0      100          0             0
#10 Leeds    bikes      13.0        3.54       0             0
```

Or if you want to fill entries across all percentage columns:

```
df %>%
    group_by(city) %>%
    mutate(
        number = as.numeric(as.character(number)),
        ntot = sum(number),
        percentage = number / ntot * 100,
        id = paste0("perc.", transport)) %>%
    spread(id, percentage) %>%
    select(-ntot) %>%
    fill(perc.bikes, perc.cars, perc.scooters, .direction = "up") %>%
    fill(perc.bikes, perc.cars, perc.scooters, .direction = "down") %>%
    replace(., is.na(.), 0) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 21 x 6
#   city     transport number perc.bikes perc.cars perc.scooters
#   <fct>    <fct>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 Aberdeen scooters   40.0        0          0           100
# 2 Bath     bikes      28.0       11.2       57.0          31.7
# 3 Bath     cars      142         11.2       57.0          31.7
# 4 Bath     scooters   79.0       11.2       57.0          31.7
# 5 Belfast  bikes       8.00       3.86      96.1           0
# 6 Belfast  cars      199          3.86      96.1           0
# 7 Derby    cars       83.0        0        100             0
# 8 Glasgow  scooters   17.0        0          0           100
# 9 Hereford bikes      23.0      100          0             0
#10 Leeds    bikes      13.0        3.54      72.8          23.7
## ... with 11 more rows
```

---

### Update

If you just want a table with percentages per city, you can do this:

```
df %>%
    group_by(city) %>%
    mutate(
        number = as.numeric(as.character(number)),
        number = number / sum(ntot) * 100,
        transport = paste0("perc.", transport)) %>%
    spread(transport, number, fill = 0)
    ungroup()
    ## A tibble: 13 x 4
    #   city        perc.bikes perc.cars perc.scooters
    #   <fct>            <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
    # 1 Aberdeen          0          0           100
    # 2 Bath             11.2       57.0          31.7
    # 3 Belfast           3.86      96.1           0
    # 4 Derby             0        100             0
    # 5 Glasgow           0          0           100
    # 6 Hereford        100          0             0
    # 7 Leeds             3.54      72.8          23.7
    # 8 Liverpool       100          0             0
    # 9 London            0         87.9          12.1
    #10 Nottingham        0        100             0
    #11 Oxford           12.8        0            87.2
    #12 Preston          37.3        0            62.7
    #13 Southampton     100          0             0
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Moving from this point on, I was just going to crunch the data frame using something like `df %>% select(., -transport, -number) %>% filter(., !duplicated(city))`

Comment: @JoRom No problem, glad to help; btw, no need for `select(., ...) %>% ...`; take a look at my updated solution. It's still not as short as the `xtabs` solution, but a lot of the excess comes about from reproducing your original expected outcome table. To get a simple prop table, this basically boils down to a single `group_by`, `mutate` and `spread` call.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes table/matrix operations can present a simple solution:

```
df$number <- as.numeric(as.character(df$number))
prop.table(xtabs(number ~ city + transport, data=df), 1)

#             transport
#city               bikes       cars   scooters
#  Aberdeen    0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
#  Bath        0.11244980 0.57028112 0.31726908
#  Belfast     0.03864734 0.96135266 0.00000000
#  Derby       0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000
#  Glasgow     0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
#  Hereford    1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
#  Leeds       0.03542234 0.72752044 0.23705722
#  Liverpool   1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
#  London      0.00000000 0.87931034 0.12068966
#  Nottingham  0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000
#  Oxford      0.12820513 0.00000000 0.87179487
#  Preston     0.37288136 0.00000000 0.62711864
#  Southampton 1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

This also gives you the flexibility to find the proportion of a type of transport in each city, just by changing one value:

```
prop.table(xtabs(number ~ city + transport, data=df), 2)
```

Comment: Again, thank you so much @thelatemail! I wasn't aware of the different possible outputs using a different index on `prop.table()` - extremely helpful and simple!